# GPS data meaning

Tags: gps

I got this data from GPS module.

> $GPRMC,235316.000,A,4003.9040,N,10512.5792,W,0.09,144.75,141112,,*19
>   $GPGGA,235317.000,4003.9039,N,10512.5793,W,1,08,1.6,1577.9,M,-20.7,M,,0000*5F

What is the meaning of these code ? How to get Latitude and longitude and how to convert that value to add GOOGLE map. I think GOOGLE map accept Decimal degree value.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've read the NMEA sentence details as per David's answer and parsed them you can use code like the following to convert to decimal degrees:

```
double lat, lon;
int degrees;

lat = atof(RMC.latitude);
lon = atof(RMC.longitude);
degrees = (int) (lat / 100);
lat = (double) degrees + (lat - degrees * 100) / 60.0;
degrees = (int) (lon / 100);
lon = (double) degrees + (lon - degrees * 100) / 60.0;
if (RMC.NS_ind == 'S')
  lat = 0.0 - lat;
if (RMC.EW_ind == 'W')
  lon = 0.0 - lon;
Latitude = lat;
Longitude = lon;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Google to search?  These are [NMEA sentences](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/) which are widely documented.

From that site:

> $GPRMC - Recommended minimum specific GPS/Transit data
>
> $GPGGA - Global Positioning System Fix Data